# How to compute with the Stark conjectures?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, computer-algebra

I would like a convenient basis for the elements of a fixed abelian extension $E$ of a real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. The accepted answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106660/kroneckers-jugendtraum-for-real-quadratic-fields/) suggests that [the Stark conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_conjectures) give explicit generators for $E$ which can then be verified using the computer algebra system [PARI/GP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP).

**Question:** Given $d$, how do I use PARI/GP to find and verify the desired generators?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main reference here is the very useful User's Guide,

- C. Batut, K. Belabas, D. Bernardi, H. Cohen, M. Olivier, "[User's Guide to PARI / GP](http://math.mit.edu/~brubaker/PARI/PARIusers.pdf)" (2003)

Particularly the sections about **bnrstark** (pp. 108), **quadhilbert** (pp. 87) and **quadray** (pp. 88).

For more information and examples you may want to look at Roblot's work, for instance

- Xavier-François Roblot, Brett A. Tangedal, "[Numerical Verification of the Brumer-Stark Conjecture](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/roblot/resources/rota.pdf)" (2000)
- Xavier-François Roblot, "[Checking the Brumer-Stark conjecture using PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/Events/IHP2004/Xavier.Roblot/ihp-brumer-stark.pdf)" (2004)